# How can I quickly get a system showing the “Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Site_Health' not found in” up and running again?

Tags: updates, fatal-error

I client of mine recently upgraded a very basic WordPress install to version 5.6.1. While the update seemed to go well, right at the very end the site died with an error that read something like this; identifying details altered for privacy:

```
[Sat Feb 06 12:12:11.123456 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 128] [client 12.34.56.78:12345] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Site_Health' not found in /var/www/html/wp-includes/rest-api.php:321
```

I have fairly deep experience debugging WordPress and related PHP sites, but this was baffling. According to them they disabled all of the plug-ins and themes and even downloaded a clean archive of WordPress 5.6.1 and did the basic manual upgrade process of retaining the `wp-config.php`, `.htaccess` and related user specific uploads in the `wp-content` directory and the error still shows up.

I’ve read advice like [what was posted here on the WordPress forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-update-to-5-6-crashed-my-site/) that basically state one should restore from a backup and try again, but find that advice to be a classic “[Hail Mary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass)” play; sometimes it works and other times you are just left in the same exact position as before but with new file modification dates.

So given that the class `WP_Site_Health` and the file `wp-includes/rest-api.php` are both items that exist in core WordPress, what can be done to quickly patch the system to get it working again?

---

P.S.: And to truly confirm the files were fine, I did the following:

- Created a Tar/Gzip archive of the whole WordPress install — including all `wp-content` items — and downloaded it to my desktop.
- Then I decompressed the archive, went into that directory and ran `git init` inside of it to create a Git repo.
- I left the site as-is as the `master` branch and then created a new branch called `test`.
- In that test branch, I manually downloaded a 100% WordPress 5.6.1 install from WordPress directly, manually copied the clean files into the new branch and committed them.
- Then I ran local `git diff master..test` to see what files were changed between the source `master` branch and the `test` branch. The diff said the files from the server versus clean WordPress 5.6.1 files were 100% the same; what was on the server is 100% the same as a clean WordPress install.

Comment: This is a classic symptom of a failed or incomplete update. The correct solution is to perform a manual update: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: @JacobPeattie And if you actually read what I posted I stated “According to them they disabled all of the plug-ins and themes and even downloaded a clean archive of WordPress 5.6.1 and did the basic manual upgrade process of retaining the `wp-config.php`, `.htaccess` and related user specific uploads in the `wp-content` directory and the error still shows up.”

Comment: "According to them". You need to verify that it was done properly.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Just updated my question to explain how I just confirmed the files were 100% the same: I downloaded the site as is, inited a Git repo in that directory, created a new branch, then manually added the files from a clean WordPress 5.6.1 and ran a basic `git diff` between the branches. The results? 100% the same… Expect for now the only file changed is the one I indicated in the answer: `wp-includes/rest-api.php`. So your advice is well intentioned — mucking with core files is not ideal — but honestly  there was no difference between the server files and clean WordPress 5.6.1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### The solution is to add a PHP `class_exists` check around line 321 in `wp-includes/rest-api.php`.

While patching WordPress core like this makes me wince, the check I added just confirms if `WP_Site_Health` exists in the code WordPress loaded to render itself. Here is what exists around line 321 in core WordPress code for `wp-includes/rest-api.php`:

```
// Site Health.
$site_health = WP_Site_Health::get_instance();
$controller  = new WP_REST_Site_Health_Controller( $site_health );
$controller->register_routes();
```

Here is what I adjusted around there to get the site back up and running:

```
// Site Health.
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Site_Health' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-site-health.php';
}
$site_health = WP_Site_Health::get_instance();
$controller  = new WP_REST_Site_Health_Controller( $site_health );
$controller->register_routes();
```

The logic is pretty simple: Using the PHP function [`class_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php), the code simply checks `WP_Site_Health` exists or not. If it doesn’t exist, then WordPress loads it using `require_once` and moves on. If it does exists? The condition fails that’s that.

It still is baffling why — if you look at [`wp-settings.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dbfbf5501a2ced1bebaf47b4eebfb79a98e01f1b/wp-settings.php) which bootstraps all of the classes when WordPress is loaded — `rest-api.php` loads around line 240, but makes a call to `WP_Site_Health` around line 539. Why would `rest-api.php` — which is loaded first — making a call to `WP_Site_Health` which only loads waaay later on in the `require` list?

Anyway, this is not pretty but it works and should be harmless to add to quickly get a site up and running again.

Comment: There’s no reason you should ever do this. All you’re doing is covering up a deeper issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at what point in your code you're making calls to the WordPress REST API or any other code which makes use of `WP_Site_Health`.

If you're making calls in your `<theme>/functions.php` file, for example, it won't work because `functions.php` is included before `class WP_Site_Health` in `wp-settings.php`.

See `wp-settings.php` code (WordPress 5.7.2):

```
// Load the functions for the active theme, for both parent and child theme if applicable.
foreach ( wp_get_active_and_valid_themes() as $theme ) {
    if ( file_exists( $theme . '/functions.php' ) ) {
        include $theme . '/functions.php';
    }
}
unset( $theme );

/**
 * Fires after the theme is loaded.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 */
do_action( 'after_setup_theme' );

// Create an instance of WP_Site_Health so that Cron events may fire.
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Site_Health' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-site-health.php';
}
WP_Site_Health::get_instance();
```

Despite the lack of elegance, one thing you can do about it is to ensure the class is loaded by copying part of the code from `wp-settings.php` and pasting it before your code. For example, in your `<theme>/functions.php`, you can do this:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Site_Health' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-site-health.php';
}
WP_Site_Health::get_instance();

---8<---
code depending on WP_Site_Health
---8<---
```

Comment: Thanks for the new post! But honestly, what is the difference between your `if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Site_Health' ) ) {` and my solution doing the exact same way? Anyway, I finally had time to go through the theme and figure out where the problematic call was in the hacked together theme we were dealing with. Fixed the issue and now the site has clean core WordPress code and the theme is a (working) mess of its own.

Comment: The difference is in where you're adding the `if`. `functions.php` is supposed to contain custom code. Modifying `wp-includes/rest-api.php` is really not what you want as it is wordpress native code. Also beware there's a huge chance you're doing something out of specs (like calling `register_rest_route()` out of the `rest_api_init` hook, for example. See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#bare-basics) to get this error.

Comment: “Also beware there's a huge chance you're doing something out of specs…” Not me! But whatever transient developer hacked together the theme that site used. Anyway, without going into ugly specifics, the issue was tracked down, isolated to the theme and all fixed now. We can now update WordPress core on the site without breaking the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was not to register rest routes inside `register_api_init`.

from:

```php
register_rest_route( 'api', '/empleados/(?P<empleadoId>\d+)', array(
    'methods'  => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'rest_get_empleado'
) );
```

to:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'api', '/empleados/(?P<empleadoId>\d+)', array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'rest_get_empleado'
    ) );
} );
```

After `rest_api_init`, the needed initialization is done and no class is missing.